# Update JSon parsed vote using Ruby on Rails, possible without JQuery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make the vote total editable from a JSon parsed API.  I have the following in my rosters controller:

```
def index
@rosters = HTTParty.get('https:api', :headers =>{'Content_Type' => 'application/json'})
 @allrosters = Roster.all
 @allrostershash = {}
 @allrosters.each do |roster|
  image_url = roster['image_url']
  @allrostershash[ image_url ] = roster 
 end
 @rosters.each do |roster|
  img_url = roster['image_url']
  unless @allrostershash[img_url]
    Roster.create(roster)
 end
end
end
  def count_vote
    roster_id = params[:id]
    roster = Roster.find_by(roster_id)
    newvote = roster.vote + 1
    if roster.update({vote: newvote})
      redirect_to rosters_path
    end
  end
```

Roster is the name of my class above.  In my rails views I have the following:

```
<% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
  <div class='each'>
    <%= image_tag(roster['image_url'], class: 'image') %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(roster['id']) %>
    <p class='name'> <%= roster['name'] %> </p>
    <p class='title'> <%= roster['title'] %> </p>
    <p> <%= roster['bio'] %> </p>
    <p> <b> Want to work with <%= roster['name'] %>? </b> <%= link_to image_tag('yes.jpg', class: 'yes'), rosters_path, method: :patch %>
    <br>
    <%= roster['vote'] %> People have said Yes! </p>
    <br>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like that every time someone clicks on yes.jpg, the roster['vote'] increases by 1.

Currently my routes are set up as follows:

```
get 'rosters', to: 'rosters#index'
patch 'rosters', to: 'rosters#count_vote'
```

I'm trying to accomplish this without jquery or ajax, that's why I have the if roster.update portion to redirect to rosters_path, so it basically refreshes the page upon click.  Right now it isn't updating the vote total however, I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I would like to do it all on a single page so if its not possible without JQuery, any guidance in right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `count_vote` is being called? You can shorten `count_vote` and make it safer  with `roster = Roster.find(params[:id]); roster.vote += 1; roster.save!; redirect_to rosters_path` Both `find` and `save!` will throw exceptions if they fail.

Comment: I believe the roster.save! raised the following error:  Couldn't find Roster without an ID.  When I try to type Roster.find(2) in the error console however, it returns me the correct value?

Comment: These are the only params currently for some reason

ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"qbORnCLNnI9P1zUZ02VEP3qJMwYOGa5sGw6KblPFj99mvjwZQj9VnDQ2e+6ZStJi3PJZ3MidSMsdoWlwOgBN9w==", "controller"=>"rosters", "action"=>"count_vote"} permitted: false>

how would I add an id param?

Answer (score 0):

`count_vote` will silently fail if it cannot find your Roster or if the update cannot be saved. Change it so it raises an exception of anything fails.

```
  def count_vote
    roster = Roster.find(params[:id])
    roster.vote += 1
    roser.save!
    redirect_to rosters_path
  end
```

[`find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) will raise `RecordNotFound` if the Roster cannot be found. [`save!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) will raise an error if the changes cannot be saved.

> *These are the only params currently for some reason ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"qbORnCLNnI9P1zUZ02VEP3qJMwYOGa5sGw6KblPFj99mvjwZQj9VnDQ2e+6ZStJi3PJZ3MidSMsdoWlwOgBN9w==", "controller"=>"rosters", "action"=>"count_vote"} permitted: false> how would I add an id param? – Sohel 5 hours ago*

I'm not very familiar with how views work, but I think as in [this example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification), I believe you need to pass the `roster` into `rosters_path`.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('yes.jpg', class: 'yes'), rosters_path(roster), method: :patch %>
```

Similarly, if you want `count_vote` to redirect back to the roster you just changed...

```
redirect_to rosters_path(roster)
```